# AllowAllUp property for TToolButton Is Not Working

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I am using Delphi XE5.

I am trying to workout as per the Delphi's help about TToolButton component.

Delphi Help Says about TToolButton.AllowAllUp property:

> Indicates whether all the tool buttons in a group can be un-selected at the same time.
>
> If AllowAllUp is set to true, all of the tool buttons in the group can be unselected. If AllowAllUp is set to false, at least one tool button in the group must be selected at any time. (Determine which tool button is initially selected by setting its Down property to true.)
>
> AllowAllUp is effective only when Grouped is true and Style is set to tbsCheck. Changing the value of AllowAllUp for one button in a group automatically changes the value for all buttons in the group.

What I have done is I have placed a TToolBar on the form and created three TToolButtons in it. Then AllowAllUp and Grouped property is set to True. Also, set Style property to tbsCheck.

When I run the application, and when I go on clicking all buttons one by one, then any one button is showing as selected, if i try to select or click on other TToolButton previous one becomes un-selected.

How to make AllowAllUp property working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These properties all work as intended. It seems that you are misunderstanding the intent of these properties.

The documentation for the [`Grouped`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolButton.Grouped) property says:

> When an unbroken sequence of adjacent tool buttons each has its Grouped property set to true and Style set to tbsCheck, then no more than one of the buttons can be selected at the same time.

The [`AllowAllUp`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolButton.AllowAllUp) property is related and described like so:

> Indicates whether all the tool buttons in a group can be unselected at
>   the same time.
>
> If AllowAllUp is set to true, all of the tool buttons in the group can
>   be unselected. If AllowAllUp is set to false, at least one tool button
>   in the group must be selected at any time. (Determine which tool
>   button is initially selected by setting its Down property to true.)
>
> AllowAllUp is effective only when Grouped is true and Style is set to
>   tbsCheck. Changing the value of AllowAllUp for one button in a group
>   automatically changes the value for all buttons in the group.

This property only has an impact when you group buttons, and what it does is control whether or not you can have zero buttons down. But once you have grouped buttons, never more than one of the group can be down at any one time.

You need to do the following:

- Set `Grouped` to `False`.
- Set `AllowAllUp` to `False`, not that it really matters but you may as well restore the default to avoid confusion.
- Set the style to `tbsCheck`.

Once you've done this you can check and uncheck the buttons independently of each other.

Comment: Hey David, Thanks a ton. Yes I think I misunderstood the statement "Indicates whether all the tool buttons in a group can be unselected at the same time." as I thought all buttons could be selected at the same time and unselected at the same time i.e. if you click any of the grouped buttons then all grouped buttons would be selected or unselected.